# javascript defines scope by script tags?

Tags: javascript

Never met this problem, and don't know why.
The only explanation is a scope issue.

In the same page, I have 2 sections of JS :

```
...
 <script type="text/javascript">
    go();
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function go()
    { alert('');  }
  </script>
...
```

This will show an error : *go is not defined*

**where**

```
...
     <script type="text/javascript">
        go();

        function go()
        { alert('');  }
      </script>
    ...
```

is working (obviously).

Does `<script>` tag creates a scope of JS ?
help ?

Comment: by using script tags you should first define the function and then call it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This isn't a scope issue. If you define a function (in the global scope) in one script element, then you can use it in another.

However, script elements are parsed and executed as they are encountered.

Hoisting won't work across script elements. A function defined in a later script element won't be available during the initial run of an earlier script element.

You either need to swap the order of your script elements, or delay the function call until after the script that defines it has run (e.g. by attaching it to an `onload` event handler).

```
<script>
    function go() {
        alert('');  
    }
</script>
<script>
    go();
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () { 
        go();
    }, false);
</script>
<script>
    function go() {
        alert('');  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @floorish — Whoops. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 8):

The html parser stops to execute your script before moving to next elements. So the next script element
is not executed until the first one is executed.

This is comparable to:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("hello") //null because the html parser hasn't met the div yet.
</script>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The other cause of this as an apparent error is if the first script block has a syntax error and is rejected in its entirety, but the second block runs on and misses its buddy code.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said already, order matters. For what it's worth, I saw this issue with an experiment (*not production!*) where I had something like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="/path/one.js" defer>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        methodInOneJs();
    </script>
</body>
```

And the browser complained with a [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined), even though `methodInOneJs()` was defined in *one.js*. This because of the `defer` attribute in the `script` that loads it. One might think that putting `defer` in the inline `script` as well would solve the issue, but [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer):

> Warning: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is
> absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no
> effect.

One quick [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11932030/5362795) (aside from removing `defer` altogether) was to use the `onload` event (again, not production, where I'd just use `src`):

```
<head>
    <script src="/path/one.js" defer>
</head>
<body onload="run();">
    <script>
        function run()
        {
            methodInOneJs();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

This is because with `defer`:

> the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed,
> but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

Emphasis on "*before firing DOMContentLoaded*". See also [how to load scripts last](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13846644/5362795).