# load script last

Tags: javascript, load

I have a webpage which lags while loading, because an script is trying to be processed. The scripts creates an iframe for an add service. My webpage load sequentially, but the script delays the entire page because it appears at the top...

Is it possible to have the script load last, but still have it appear at the top of the page?

Edit:
I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  window.onlaod=function(){
  var root = document.body.getElementById('top-banner');
  var oJs = document.createElement('script');
  oJs.setAttribute('type','text/JavaScript');
  oJs.setAttribute('src','http://anetwork.ir/showad/?adwidth=468&adheight=60&aduser=1341223032');
  root.appendChild(oJs);
  }
</script>
```

top-banner is the ID for div i want to show the ad. it is empty.

Comment: why dont you move the script to the end of the code?

Comment: I assume that you mean that the `script` tag is in the head. Right?

Comment: the script is an ad service which creates the ad in it's place. so i can't move it to end. also the script is not in head, it's in body.

Comment: Add the script on `window.onload` or `body.onload` so that they run after the page has loaded.

Comment: @powerbuoy, where i have to add window.onload?

Comment: What you have in your updated question _should_ work, but you have a typo: `window.onlaod` should be `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems on the load of a script because it's execution you should use functions to call that script, so, if you have a function for the script or it's automatic, you should put the script causing problems inside of a function.

When that's done you could add the `onload` property in the `body` tag and then call the `function` that creates the `iframe`:

```
<body onload="createIframe()">...</body>
```

Like this your script will be loaded just when the `body` has finished loading.

Edit:

Modify your script like that and keep the body onload showed before:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function createIframe(){
  var root = document.getElementById('top-banner');
  var oJs = document.createElement('script');
  oJs.setAttribute('type','text/JavaScript');
  oJs.setAttribute('src','http://anetwork.ir/showad/?adwidth=468&adheight=60&aduser=1341223032');
  root.appendChild(oJs);
}
</script>
```

Comment: in fact i have a div which includes an script. i just want that script be loaded last.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a best practice to include the script in the head? Like that you could initialise the script when you want without that kind of problems and you would have a total control of what scripts are being executed at any time.

Comment: Oh in var root = document.body, ... remove 'body' like in my last edit.

Comment: script was loaded, but instead of iframe, it created this: document.write('<iframe src="http://anetwork.ir/showad/c.php?adwidth=468&adheight=60&aduser=1341223032" height="60" width="468" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>')

Comment: What should be exactly the result? Because it now seems to be an error inside the function and not with the JavaScript call

Comment: i think it's a problem with document.write. Maybe i can put the script in the footer, to create the iframe, and then change the location of the iframe. but i don't khnow how!

Comment: In the piece of code you added there isn't any document.write, are you talking about another script? Could you add that to help you?

Comment: the createIframe function, creates the script in the right place, i mean top banner. but the script cannot creat the iframe. just like it's not loaded correctly.

Comment: Couldn't you create the iframe by yourself? Like you're using a function to create a script that creates an iframe, if you know exactly how the iframe has to be and the url of itself, couldn't you pass the middle step and go to the final result? Like that possibly you could avoid problems.

Comment: thanks for all your help, this link helped me at last: http://geek.littleredstring.com/17-load-adsense-last-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `script` tag to the end of the page (just after the `</body>` tag, for example).If you wanna modify previous elements of your page in function of the javascript code, you need to make it using javascript code.

That is: If you wanna load data from the server, for example, and show it formatted, you must show the HTML and then, when the script and the data is loaded, "parse" the results and "insert it" in the HTML using javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific JS code to load last:

```
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    (function($) {
        //use window.bind to load the tinymce per last. Otherwise will throw error
        $(window).bind("load", function() {
           // code here will load after page is loaded
        });
    })(jQuery);
}
```