# How to get a script to load last on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, rss, load

I have a webpage with mostly basic HTML on it. There is one section where I load an RSS feed using JavaScript pulling from an external source (url). The problem is that my page will load everything up until that script, wait for the script to load (sometimes up to a few seconds), then load the rest of the page.

How can I force it to load the script after it has rendered the entire page first?

My code is something like this:

```
<html>
<more html>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://..." type="text/javascript"></script>
<more html>
...
```

Comment: Place the script at the bottom, or use async loading.

Comment: @Cthulhu I'm pretty sure it's the opposite. The browser parses from top to bottom, and waits for the script to load. Otherwise, how else do you expect code immediately after a library that uses it to run? The browser won't wait for an image's URL to resolve and load though

Comment: @Cthulhu, they load in order and block the rest of the page. If they didn't the required libraries of another library might cause problems. For example, a small jQuery plugin would get loaded before jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure nothing immediately needs to use the Javascript library? If nothing does, use `defer` or `async` attributes on the script tag

Comment: @Cthulhu, most do, because parsing cannot continue until synchronous undeffered scripts run.  There's no way to correctly parse `<script>if (Math.random() < 0.5) { document.write("<!--"); }</script><b -->Hello, World!` without executing the script tag.

Comment: My mistake :) Was thinking something else entirely. (removed incorrect comment that said `most browsers don't wait for the script to load`.)

Comment: Both "defer" and "async" fail to load the script. The entire page is rendered, but no RSS feed is displayed

Answer (score 12):

Two options:

1. Put your script block at the end of the page. This is good practice anyways due to the fact that your page strucutre will load before the script that is intended to manipulate it. Because the user generally notices the page loading but not the script, this gives the appearance of a faster load overall.
2. Include the `defer` attribute in the opening `script` tag. Note that `defer` can only be used on *external* script files (those with an `src` attribute). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script.

Comment: 1. I have it at a certain part of my page because I want it to be displayed there. If I were to put it at the bottom, it would not be in the right place.

2. Both "defer" and "async" fail to load the script. The entire page is rendered, but no RSS feed is displayed.

Comment: Is your script externally referenced?

Comment: Yes, I have "src" pulling in a url location for the RSS feed.

Comment: Can you not pull the input into a variable? If you referenced the RSS directly you could use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery and then update an element of your choosing with the content. This would allow you to move the script tag.

Answer (score 5):

Add the `defer` attribute to the script tag in the head also works

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://..." type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

Reference link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer

Comment: Can you give me a link to an explanation of `defer` and an official document for reference?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Introducing the answers will be of greater help to the questioner and other community members.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty reliable way to make a script load after pageload is to write out the script include itself in javascript.

```
var theScript = document.createElement("script");
theScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
theScript.setAttribute("src","//www.mysite.com/script.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(theScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping the function that calls  the feed in

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
//embed RSS feed 
});
```

forcing it to load last.

Answer (score 0):

Move your script tag to the end and it will load after everything else. For example:

```
<html>
  <more html>
  <more html>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="http://..." type="text/javascript"></script>
</html
```