# Is it possible to use $_SESSION with a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a Javascript file `main.js` and I need to use `echo $_SESSION["username"]` within it, but it doesn't work obviously. Is there any way I can do this / some kind of workaround?

Comment: `PHP` will not be executed on a `.js` file.

Comment: You have the option to do a ajax call to retrieve the session value you need

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute PHP code in a .js file but there are ways to work around it. You could use an ajax call to get that variable (check out [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) for ajax tips).

Depending on the information you wish to store, you could also get PHP to echo it into a specific element in your html page and then use JS to look up that element like this:

```
echo "<span id='usernameForJS' style='display: none;'>".$_SESSION['USERNAME']."</span>";
```

And then go and grab that elements inner html with JS like this:

```
var username = document.getElementById('usernameForJS').innerHTML;
```

I would advise AJAX just because then there is no need for almost redundant elements in your page. And obviously don't use the second method for anything sensitive.

Comment: I've been doing this but moved all of the Javascript into its own file because it was getting too long. Can I on log in, redirect them to a html page that does that and sets a cookie using JS, then straight after redirect them back to the main page where the `main.js` can then access that cookie value?

Comment: You could, yes. You would just need to use PHP [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect you to the page you want to do it. I'm not entirely sure why you want to do this on a different page when you could do it at the top of the current page but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Wait can JS set in another file be accessed in `main.js`?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10968937/2233391) might help. The scope of your JS is defined by the order that they are loaded. You obviously can't do something like `go(); function go(){ alert();} ` because when you call `go();` you haven't actually defined what `go();` it is yet. If I had two files included in `<script>` tags, `first.js` and `second.js` and the first had the function declaration in and the second called the function, it would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option I saw on css-tricks.com

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/use-php-inside-javascript/

I have never tried on my own but commentators said it works.

There is also a explanation of how you could do this in the comments: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/use-php-inside-javascript/#comment-85757

But don't forget taht this is a rather "hacky" way to do it, you should consider to open that javascript file and instantiate your class/function(or whatever is in this file) from the .php-page.